# clear boost cached pages as the content is changed

Tags: caching

I am using boost with Maximum Cache Lifetime = 1 Day and Maximum Cache Lifetime = 0 Sec

If i do update some content / banners, i have to clear caches at

> /admin/config/development/performance

Is this the only way? There is no way that changed nodes/frontPage cache will be automatically cleared instantly ? and all users will see new content instead of asking them to use Ctrl + f5.

any clues 
thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Cache Expiration](https://drupal.org/project/expire) module to expire caches when content is updated.

The expire module provides the events that fire when content is updated and other caching modules hook into those events and clear their caches.

The boost module supports the expire module's events.

Once installed, you can configure the module at admin/config/system/expire.

Answer (score 0):

You can use drush as well. If you have [drush aliases](https://www.drupal.org/node/1401522) configured, just do this:
    drush @name_of_alias cc all

I'm using Drush 8 and Drupal 7, but this also worked on my earlier versions.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correct, I had a similar issue once: It's a known problem; The fact the Drush's cache isn't separate and being cleared in any general cache-clearing is problematic especially in sites where there are only tens or hundreds of users daily (and not thousands or much more) because than you need to wait everyone to rebuild the cache for you.

The solution I had in the time is pretty lame: If you site doesn't have more than some thousands of users a day - Just don't use Boost. It's a heavy module designed in the time only or mostly for large-scale sites by terms of users, so I stopped using it at the time.

We can hope that in **Drupal 8** the Boost's caching system will be totally or partly separated from the general caching system...

---

If you actually meant to ask what is the fastest way to clear cache than instead navigation to the address you posted (with or without a browser bookmark) you could install Admin_menu for Drupal 7 or Admin_toolbar for Drupal 8 and they would not only give you a cool icon to clear cache instantly on every page but a comfortable management menu on top of your browsers fold.

In Drush master you could do "`drush cr`" (this stands for drush cache rebuild).

That's aside of using cache expiration mentioned in other comments.